# Not Allow users to see another User´s Items, but the Site Owners

Tags: workflow, list-item

In order to create a Workflow process...

I would like to know if there is a way of not allow the users to see the items that a different user has created BUT allow the Site Owner (or the Workflow responsibles) check all the Items in order to verify those.

I know that there is the Option in the advanced Settings of the List but I don´t see the Option to allow the Site Owners.

Thanks in advance!